# TypeScript: Create typed Record without explicitly defining the keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

What I'd like to do is to create an object which is a Record of a certain interface and have TypeScript be able to infer the keys based on what's in my object. I've tried a few things, none of which do exactly what I'm looking for.

```
interface Person {
  firstName:string
}

const peopleObj = {
  Jason: {
    firstName: "Jason"
  },
  Tim: {
    firstName: "Tim"
  }
} as const;

console.log(peopleObj);
```

Here, if you look at peopleObj, TypeScript knows the exact keys because of the `as const`. The problem here is I'm not enforcing each object to be a `Person`. So I tried this next:

```
const peopleObj: Record<string, Person> = {
  Jason: {
    firstName: "Jason"
  },
  Tim: {
    firstName: "Tim"
  }
} as const;
```

Here, each object has to be a `Person` because of the `Record` defined, but TypeScript loses its ability to know all of the keys because now they are just `string` instead of the constants `'Jason' | 'Tim'`, and this is the crux of the issue. I know I could explicitly use `'Jason' | 'Tim'` in place of my `string` type, but this is a fairly large object in real life and updating that type explicitly every time I add to it or remove from it is getting to be tedious.

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds, where I can have TypeScript infer the keys in the object just based solely on what's in the object? I have found *a* way, although it's not super clean and I feel like there's likely a better way:

```
interface Person {
  firstName:string
}

type PeopleType<T extends string> = Record<T, Person>;

const peopleObj: Record<string, Person> = {
  Jason: {
    firstName: "Jason"
  },
  Tim: {
    firstName: "Tim"
  }
} as const;

const People:Record<keyof typeof peopleObj, Person> = peopleObj;

console.log(People.Jason);
```

Comment: For the "pure interface" problem and solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64641417

Answer (score 3):

Your third method doesn't actually work I believe - as you can access People.foo without error. This is because when you construct peopleObj as `Record<string, Person>`, its type is now that. You then do `keyof Record<string, Person>`, which evaluates to string.

The only way I'm aware of to achieve this is via using a function with generics. This allows you to apply a constraint on the input parameter, and then return the original type.

```js
const createPeople = <T extends Record<string, Person>>(people: T) => people;

const myPeople = createPeople({
  Jason: {
    firstName: "Jason"
  },
  Tim: {
    firstName: "Tim"
  }
});

console.log(myPeople.Jason);
console.log(myPeople.foo); // error
```

You have a catch 22 situation otherwise - i.e - I want to enforce that my keys are of type Person, but I don't know what my keys are.

One other way that you may prefer - which is basically the same thing but without the function:

```js
interface Person {
  firstName:string
}

// Force evaluation of type to expanded form
type EvaluateType<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

type PeopleType<T extends Record<string, Person>> = EvaluateType<{[key in keyof T]: Person }>;

const peopleLookup = {
  Jason: {
    firstName: "Jason"
  },
  Tim: {
    firstName: "Tim"
  }
};

const people: PeopleType<typeof peopleLookup> = peopleLookup;

console.log(people.Jason);
console.log(people.foo);
```

Comment: It is a bit of a contrived example for simplicity's sake. The function method does work for what I need, I just wonder if there's a way to do it without the need for a function. If not, this works, thanks!

Comment: yep - can't argue with that. I've realised there is an alternative - it involves duplicating the type though, see what you think

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding on @mbdavis's answer because there seems to be an additional constraint, which is that the key for each `Person` in the record is that `Person`'s `firstName` property.  This allows us to use mapped types.

A `PeopleRecord` should be an object such that for every key `name`, the value is either a `Person` object with `{firstName: name}` or `undefined`;

```
type PeopleRecord = {
    [K in string]?: Person & {firstName: K} 
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work the way we want it to if we just apply this type to `peopleObj`, since it doesn't see the names as anything more specific than `string`.  Maybe another user can figure out how to make it work, but I can't.

Like @mbdavis, I need to reassign the object to enforce that it matches a more specific constraint.

I use the mapped type `ValidateRecord<T>` which takes a type `T` and forces that every key on that type is a `Person` with that first name.

```
type ValidateRecord<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Person & {firstName: P}
}
```

Now we can reassign your `peopleObj`, which should only work if the object is valid, and will throw errors otherwise.

```
const validatedObj: ValidateRecord<typeof peopleObj> = peopleObj;
```

But it's a lot cleaner to do this assertion through a function.  Note that the function itself merely returns the input.  You could do any other validation checking on the JS side of things here.

```
const asValid = <T extends {}>( record: T & ValidateRecord<T> ): ValidateRecord<T> => record;
```

```
const goodObj = {
  Jason: {
    firstName: "Jason"
  },
  Tim: {
    firstName: "Tim"
  }
} as const;

// should be ok
const myRecordGood = asValid(goodObj);

// should be a person with {firstName: "Tim"}
const A = myRecordGood["Tim"]

// should be a problem
const B = myRecordGood["Missing"]

const badObj = {
  Jason: {
    firstName: "Bob"
  },
  Tim: {
    firstName: "John"
  }
} as const;

// should be a problem
const myRecordBad = asValid(badObj);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsjMFBmAHJwC2EAXMlVKAOYDcxAvscWACeABxQA1OABtgAEziQAShARYoMgDwAVAHzIAvPmKlSAbVTJQyANYRBWGMk0BdZuko5kAMnzlKNekxofETBxCogVMiiWMKSEADyAEYAVvqGJMgAUnDYIMyEGaS%20VLQMzABE2bnlRsg8ADS1msB0%20bVFFCUBFc10NRnBPMg5yOFU-ERjYMgAblKy8hAyScnMEtJyisqqGkLRDtGxCSm6BodxK9xEYTiROeuyaVrIEAAekCAyGPg82gAUyCg2zUzE0XmQD02ECUKjUWl0AEo1vMoTCdvD9LogbCZFcbhFpuwsFhlik0gVSFUcG1CmROv4yshKjkcP1SA0mi0acY6X5SoFyr02XVeMNvlM8UQAPRSlgACywAFdJDJkIkUFgrPjInRBGi1ABxYmqgz3FF-IkklYIyUy%20VKlVqlBwKKYDwAd2AYDlPnp-J6LXKwSmyAAgmldfqZEaSSZBYGnBM7RgFcrVerhlEoFhEnE6NrpgAhCN64HR41xgCywAwGA45UT10mt2miTgpNSBgpWRZeXSPOKDIFhZzwo5GV63OMg-9TMyWDlIDHopGEqTspTDvTzqzObzBeQkbLhfbaTNGz%20bY7NqAA)