# TypeScript: Inherit the type of values, not all the keys, from a Record<> interface

Tags: typescript, interface, record, extend

I have a main interface in my project which dictates the `value` type of the properties of the extending objects.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume it is like this:

```
interface Printable extends Record<PropertyKey, string> {
}
```

It just says all the `value`s should be `string`.  And it properly prohibits its extending interfaces to have a `number` key, like below.

```
interface Receipt extends Printable {
    customerName: string;
    // customerId: number;  // EXPECTED: This line errors if uncommented (Property 'customerId' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'string'. (2411))
}
```

However, the unwanted side-effect is that it widens the "key" range to be "any `string`", so it doesn't catch the following error:

```
const r: Receipt = { customerName: "Jack" };
console.log(r.address); // UNEXPECTED: This line DOESN'T error "for Property 'address' does not exist on type 'Receipt'.(2339)"
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApVGOAjANiiAD0hABMBnZAJQgQHspSAedOgB2jAE8BpCLgDTJyYDCADmAPmQBvAFByAvgszR4SarQjA2YZERIU0YrHhTyAkAgCuIugFtoAOTiOAXMNGhxAbjlXbMAdoAElSDxBre2xoH2RkAHoE5ABRAA1UFIBhABUUgBEPHIALYEpcUBRyYrprXFJ9KCgGJQV6EBFkKA8aJB09AF5ZZBs7RygXd2QAIgApRABraeRFP3byOnwAOlw6cQAKKC24UlIoCHJyAEo4pOQAVSd0zNyCotLyyuRSOguQAHI9NBmlAgA)

#### Question

How can I get the "**enforced value type**" benefit from a super-interface, without the unwanted "**widened key range**"?

---

PS.  It's different from [TypeScript: Create typed Record without explicitly defining the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119527/typescript-create-typed-record-without-explicitly-defining-the-keys) in the sense that here I want an *interface* with no overhead on the objects or their instantiation.  Please stop reporting it as a duplicate. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Create typed Record without explicitly defining the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119527/typescript-create-typed-record-without-explicitly-defining-the-keys)

Comment: @mbdavis: No actually, but very close.  The biggest difference is, over there you need to do something abnormal at the "object creation/instantiation" time, per object instance.  Here, I don't want that.  I want the magic to happen at the "interface" creation time, so object instantiation would be normal.  And my reason for that is I want to leave the least amount of footprint in the codebase, of this magic, until TS provides a universal solution for such a thing.  Thanks anyway.

PS. Aleksey's solution is very close to yours over there (just instance-agnostic) and should work for me.

Comment: ok awesome. glad it's sorted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create utility type based on [generic type constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to validate input type values:

```
type Printable<T extends Record<PropertyKey, string>> = T;

type Receipt = Printable<{
    customerName: string;
    // customerId: number; // Expect error
}>

const r: Receipt = { customerName: "Jack" };
console.log(r.address); // Property 'address' does not exist on type '{ customerName: string; }'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwHbAIYCMA2EA8AVKCAD2AiQBMBnKAJQgGMB7OcneRyOUAaQhABoolYIiQBzAHwSoAXih4A3ACgloSLQYQEYYLNii0WXAG8lUc1HoBXYYwC2EOADlUDgFxCRyMcotQA9P6WNsD2jgCS5B5IVnbojgoBQQCiRJD0uo5wzEoAvhIqTEjCUHAedPRaOnrGwbYOzq4QHgBEAFKo9ADWLVC5ykWUjNgAdJiMYgAUcCOo5ORwEJSUAJSJgfocjqBQAORzC0uUu1DkjEtQSIyZRAgljEhQatC7tdb1ji7unqI%20fbsjIA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible at least now, because you have to do something like this:

```
interface Printable extends Record<keyof Printable, string> {

}
```

Which gives an error regarding the recursive use of `Printable interface` and doesn't make much sense tbh. the only solution that comes to my mind, is like below.

```
type StringOnly<T extends string> = Record<T, string>

type Printable = StringOnly<"key1" | "key2" | "key3">

interface Receipt extends Printable {
    customerName: string;
}

const r: Receipt = { customerName: "Jack"};
console.log(r.address); // Property 'address' does not exist on type 'Receipt'.(2339)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mahdi. Manually typing all the key names (in `StringOnly<...>`) is not scalable for me.  I think Aleksey L.'s solution works better.