# Is it possible to infer the keys of an object that is predefined?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object:

```
const obj = {
    a: {...},
    b: {...},
    ...
}
```

In ts if I'll create a type:

```
type oT = keyof typeof obj;
```

I'll get the union of the keys..

I want to define 'obj' as a record type e.g

```
type myType = Record<string, IMyInterface>;
const obj: myType ={...}
```

but still infer the keys for oT type, how can I do that?

Comment: How would the keys of the record be defined ?

Comment: "I want to define 'obj' as a record type" <-- can you show what you're talking about with a [mre]?  Right now we'd have to guess what this means exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Create typed Record without explicitly defining the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119527/typescript-create-typed-record-without-explicitly-defining-the-keys)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
const _obj = {
    a: { name: 'alex' },
    b: { age: 1 },
    c: 'hello',
}
type oT = keyof typeof _obj;
const obj = _obj as Record<oT, any>; // use obj going forward
```

Comment: That's defining the interface of obj...