# Can you define a type that has fixed keys at object creation, with values of a given type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using MaterialUI's `sx` property to style some react components. I find having the full style definition inline with the components leads to messy, screen filling component bodies, so I have moved all the style definitions into a constant object outside the function component. Here's a quick example:

```
const styles = {
    a: {/*...*/}
    b: {/*...*/}
}

const component = () => <Box sx={styles.a}>
        <Button sx={styles.b}>Button Text</Button>
    </Box>
```

The problem I'm having is ensuring that styles.a and styles.b are valid objects, which is difficult without the IDE knowing what types they should be. If I declare `styles: Record<string, SystemStyleObject>` I gain type checking when defining a and b, but I lose knowledge over the actual keys of `styles` and accessing `styles.c` no longer errors.

I've come up with two clunky work-arounds:

### #1 Declare the individual variables and then collect them into an object

```
const a: SystemStyleObject = {}
const b: SystemStyleObject = {}

const styles = {a, b}
```

This gets me to the end product I want, but it requires declaring every single style in a separate variable, as well as explicity typing them.

### #2 Pass a union of the objects keys as the first argument to record

```
const styles: Record<'a' | 'b', SystemStyleObject> = {
    a: {/*...*/}
    b: {/*...*/}
}
```

This also gets me to the same end product, but makes adding or changing the keys of the object awkward as you have to add them to the union as well as the body.

#2 is the one I've gone with for now, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for code completion in vscode:**

You can import `SxProps` property directly from MUI, use it to describe your style objects and enjoy working IDE code completion. There also should be installed [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components) extension

```
import { SxProps } from '@mui/material/styles';

type StylesObjectType = {
  [key:string]:SxProps
}

const styles: StylesObjectType = {
  a: {
    border: "1px solid red",
  }
};
```

For the second part of the question - here are
[suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119527/typescript-create-typed-record-without-explicitly-defining-the-keys) on how to create a typed Record without explicitly defining the keys.

Comment: This has the same problem as `Record<string, SystemStyleObject>`, where there's no code completion on the properties of `styles`, and accessing `styles.c` is not an error.

Comment: I've just noticed that there should be installed `vscode-styled-components` extension for vscode to make code completion work.